# In a Quiz of 100 quesions the questionsArray is mapped so how to easily store the question, selected option and answer of questions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a quiz using React but stuck at counting the marks and displaying all the questions with answer solution in next page.

I have 100 questions like this.

```js
const questionsArr = [
 {
  question: "Grand Central Terminal, Park Avenue, New York is the world's",
  options: ["largest railway station", "highest railway station", "longest railway station", "None of the above"],
  answer: "largest railway station"
 },
 {
  question: "Entomology is the science that studies",
  options: ["Behavior of human beings", "Insects", "The origin and history of technical and scientific terms", "The formation of rocks"],
  answer: "The origin and history of technical and scientific terms"
 },
 {
  question: "Eritrea, which became the 182nd member of the UN in 1993, is in the continent of",
  options: ["Asia", "Africa", "Europe", "Australia"],
  answer: "Africa"
 },
 {
  question: "Hitler party which came into power in 1933 is known as",
  options: ["Labour Party", "Nazi Party", "Ku-Klux-Klan","Democratic Party"],
  answer: "Nazi Party"
 } 
]
```

In the component below the MCQ child is mapped.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {

  render() {
  return(
    <form>
      <div>
      {questionsArr.map(item => <MCQ question=  {item.question} options={item.options} answer={item.answer} />)}
      </div>
      <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
  }
}
```

```js
class MCQ extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
         <h1>{this.props.question}</h1>
         <label><input type="radio" name={this.props.question} value={this.props.options[0] answer={this.props.answer}} {this.props.options[0]}</label>
         <label><input type="radio" name={this.props.question} value={this.props.options[1] answer={this.props.answer}} {this.props.options[1]}</label>
         <label><input type="radio" name={this.props.question} value={this.props.options[2] answer={this.props.answer}} {this.props.options[2]}</label>
         <label><input type="radio" name={this.props.question} value={this.props.options[3] answer={this.props.answer}} {this.props.options[3]}</label>
         
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**I just want to know how can I store and get the values (like question, selected option, answer etc) of all 100 questions mapped so that it can be accessible in new page after the button is submitted.**

Comment: can you create codesandbox? to see what you already done.

Comment: <label><input type="radio" name={this.props.question} value={this.props.options[0] answer={this.props.answer}} {this.props.options[0]} /></label> you missed to close all inputs between labels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start by reading https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Summary:

1. Declare a state in `Test`
2. Update this state when checking an option via an `onChange` handler on checkbox inputs

The state could look like `[{questionId: 1, answerId: 2}, {questionId: 2, answerId: 0}, ..., {questionId: 100, answerId: null}]` assuming you have ids for questions and answers, which you should have if the questions are stored in a database. You then update the relevant `answerId` each time an answer is changed.

P.S.: You probably don't want to store the correct answer on the frontend, as those who take the quizz will have access to them. Rather, you should validate the answers given on the backend side

Comment: I have **onChange** handler that gets the values when the radio buttons are changed.

BUT

I have **100** of questions mapped from an array. So how do I store all those questions selected answer in state as there will be 100 of variables.

Comment: I updated the answer to detail what the state could look like